# Is there any way to Disable Edge from saving search history into Microsoft Account?

Tags: browser, privacy, history, microsoft-edge

By setting edge with bing as the default, every search is in fact stored in Microsoft Accounts/Privacy/Search. The user is automatically logged in with the WIN 10 ID.

Is there any way to prevent this? Setting BING search history as off only keeps bing history off.

Or is this done on purpose by Microsoft?

Comment: Try disabling page prediction. Just a guess.

Comment: Max - Have a look at [Microsoft Edge, browsing data, and privacy](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-microsoft-edge-and-privacy) and read it over from top to bottom. This should explain the why and how and give you the steps to disable. This should be easy enough for you to test and confirm at least but let me know if you find this helpful in your quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two solutions (which you might not like):

1. Use another browser than Edge or don't used Bing.
2. Don't use a Microsoft account, which is where your data is stored.
   See the article
   [How to Revert Your Windows 10 Account to a Local One](https://www.howtogeek.com/230543/how-to-revert-your-windows-10-account-to-a-local-one-after-the-windows-store-hijacks-it/).

While you are about it, you might also disable the biggest threat to your
privacy : Cortana (See [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/265027/how-to-disable-cortana-in-windows-10/)). Point 2 above will also block Cortana.

As another remark, third-party apps are always safe :
If you don't use Windows 10 apps for browsing, search and mail, no history is kept.

Answer (score 0):

Open your start menu -> Settings -> Privacy -> Feedback & Diagnostics -> And set "Diagnostic and usage data" to basic

[Source](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-microsoft-edge-and-privacy)